# an example of Zariski cotangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying these very nice [notes](http://livetoad.org/Courses/Documents/8875/Notes/differentials_and_the_zariski_tangent_space.pdf) on the Zariski tangent space.

Let $f \in K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and let $V=Z(f)$, the zero set of $f$.
Let $P \in V$ and let $M_P$ denote the vanishing ideal of point $P$.
We define a map $d: K[V] \rightarrow K$ by sending $g \in K[V]$ to
the image of $g(x)-g(P)$ in $M_P/M_P^2$. Then $df = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_P dx_i$, which comes from taking the class mod $M_P^2$ of the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $P$.

My question is: why do we have that $df=0$?
This appears to be the case in the example presented in the beginning of page 3 in the notes i refer to. Note that according to the definitions $df= \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_P (x_i-a_i) + M_P^2$, where $P=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$.

Comment: What is $f$ as a function on $Z(f)$?

Comment: @Andrew: Zero of course. But according to the definitions, $df = \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (x-a_i) + M_P^2$, where $P=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$. Why is this zero? Or equivalently, why is $\sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} (x-a_i)$ inside $M_P^2$?

Comment: Manos: remember that $M_P$ means the maximal ideal of $P$ in the coordinate ring of $V$. Think about what Taylor expansion tells you about $f-∑∂f/∂x_i(x−a_i)$...

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: The Taylor expansion tells me that $f- \sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_P (x_i - a_i)$ is inside $M_P^2$. I can't see anything more...I think i am missing something fundamental.

Comment: But what is $f$ in this ring?

Comment: After all, the equation $\sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_P(x_i-a_i) = 0$ essentially defines the tangent space as a linear subvariety of $\mathbb A^n.$ E.g., if $n=2,f=x, P=(0,1)$ then $df = x\notin M_P^2$ if $M_P$ is the maximal ideal in $K[x,y].$ We must work modulo $f,$ as Asal explains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $df := f - f(P) \bmod M_p^2$, where $f$ is viewed as an element of the coordinate ring
$$
 K[V] := K[x_1,\dotsc,v_n]/I[V];
$$ 
in particular, $M_p$ is an ideal in $K[V]$, not in $K[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$.

Now, if $f \in I[V]$ (e.g., if $V = Z(f)$), then $f = 0 \bmod I[V]$ and $f(P) = 0$, and hence $f - f(P) = f = 0$ already in $K[V] \supset M_p$. Thus, *a fortiori*, $f - f(P) = 0 \bmod M_p^2$ in $M_p \subset K[V]$, so that by definition of $df \in T_p^\ast V$, $df = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. To be honest, though, this had me scratching my head for a while too.

Comment: Could you also please explain how do we obtain algebraically the equation $\sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}|_P (x_i-a_i)=0$ as the equation for the tangent space? In the notes that i am referring to, this is presented with no comment.

Comment: So, for $P \in Z(f)$, we have that
$$
 0 = df = \sum_{k=1}^n \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}|_P dx_k
$$
in $T^\ast_P V(f) = \left(T_P V(f)\right)^\ast$. Hence, for any $v := \sum_{k=1}^N v_k D_{e_k}|_P \in T_P V(f)$,
$$
 0 = df(v) = \sum_{k=1}^n \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}|_P v_k,
$$
which is the abstract form of the equation you're interested in. But then, just as in the differential-geometric case, if you view $V(f)$ as embedded in $K^n$, then the equation of the tangent space $T_P V(f)$ to $V(f)$ at $P$, viewed as an affine subspace of $K^n$, translates precisely to your equation.